# "Slope Analogue" of Clothoids

Tags: reference-request, differential-equations, curves-and-surfaces

It is well known, that the characterizing property of Clothoids is, that their curvature is proportional to length; that is also the reason, why they are used as design elements e.g. in road design.

> **Question:**
>   Has the analogue to clothoids, where the slope and not the curvature is proportional to length, ever been described or investigated?

The associated differential equation
$$y'(x) =\int_0^x \sqrt{1+y'(t)^2} dt $$  isn't hard to devise and the curve might also have practical applications also e.g. in road design.

I am specifically looking for articles on the solution of the associated differential equation, but other articles related to the curve are also welcome.

Comment: Don't you need $y'(t)^2$ on the right?

Comment: Yes, you are right; I overlooked that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $y''(x)=\sqrt{1+y'(x)^2}$ so $u=y'$ satisfies $u'(x)=\sqrt{1+u^2}$. This is separable, so we get
$$
\frac{du}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}=dx,\quad \sinh^{-1}(u)=x + C.
$$

Comment: In other words $y$ is (more or less just) $\cosh(x)$, a catenary curve, which is indeed used [a lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary) in architecture. I find especially spectacular [the use of catenary revolution shapes by Innuits when building igloos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenoid#Architecture)

Comment: Not to forget the catenoid, a minimum area surface of revolution that isometrically deforms to a helicoid.